# How do I convert/cast a string into a bool in Tcl?

Tags: string, casting, boolean, tcl

I was expecting

```
if {[some_func $some_args]} {
   ....
}
```

to eval true and simply work as soon as `some_func` returns some string. However there are errors.

Learning it the hard way, Tcl accepts only the

- empty string -> False
- 0 -> False
- false -> False
- true -> True
- 1 -> True

To be precise:

```
% expr 1
1
% expr 0
0
% expr
wrong # args: should be "expr arg ?arg ...?"
% expr {{}}
% expr true
true
% expr false
false
% expr True
syntax error in expression "True": variable references require preceding $
% expr False
syntax error in expression "False": variable references require preceding $
```

It seems `expr` does not normalize it's return value. Note especially the empty string result if an empty string is given.

So how do I easily convert strings into booleans?

Comment: Strictly, there's a small set of strings that are considered to be interpretable as booleans; the other possibilities… aren't. If that's not enough, I'd just encourage thinking out what you really mean; what sort of test do you really want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After thinking some more, and looking some more, the answer probably should be: "It depends"

With my perl background I was expecting something similar to perl. My fault.

In Tcl `string is true` seems to be the official cast function. Valid strings for casting are [defined here](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclLib/GetInt.htm):

> If string is any of 0, false, no, or off, then Tcl_GetBoolean stores a
>   zero value at *boolPtr. If string is any of 1, true, yes, or on, then
>   1 is stored at *boolPtr. Any of these values may be abbreviated, and
>   upper-case spellings are also acceptable

In my case, I don't care about the string's content so I can just

```
if {[string length [some_func $some_args]] > 0} {
  ...
}
```

Another way to write this also is much simpler:

```
if {[some_func $some_args] != {}} {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is correct answer. Also since 8.4 you can also write `if {[some_func $some_args] ne ""}` which is a bit less "qurly-bracey".

Comment: I would also note that I perceive Tcl's way to deal with booleans to be more sensible than that found in Perl and PHP with their idiotic type conversions.  The only Tcl's blunder in this venue is the dreaded [octal problem](http://wiki.tcl.tk/498) which, we hope, will be solved in 9.0 ;-)

Comment: @kostix: +1 [_Ceterum censeo octal numeros esse delendam._](http://www.tcl.tk/cgi-bin/tct/tip/114.html)

Answer (score 2):

From the perspective of the user, Tcl doesn't have the ability or need to "cast" values from one type to another. Rather, everything is a string and you ask "Can this value be interpreted as a ?" For example:

```
set value 1
string is boolean $value
> 1
string is integer $value
> 1

set value true
string is boolean $value
> 1
string is integer $value
> 0
```

There are also some `[string is]` subcommands that check for specific values, but that is mostly for convenience. For example:

```
string is true $value
# effectively equivalent to
expr {[string is boolean $value] && $value}
```

So, that being said, the strings that can be interpreted as true have varied over time, if I recall correctly. My recommendation is to always use "true" or "false", since all versions of Tcl (I think) recognize them as boolean and they accurately represent the intent of it being boolean (which I don't think 1/0 do).

If what you're really trying to do is find out if you have a string with actual content in it, then just use:

```
if {[string length $value] > 0} { ....}
```

If what you're trying to do is emulate some other language's version of truthiness, then my recommendation would be *don't do that*. Sure, you can, via

```
if { (![string is false $value]) && [string length $value] > 0 } { ... }
```

but that's probably not the right way to go.

Comment: Under the covers, Tcl actually does all that type conversion stuff. However, that's considered to be a feature of the implementation and not of the language; the Tcl _language_ is untyped.

Comment: Hence the phrase "From the perspective of the user" :)